# jQuery selector doesn't work with WP menu item anchor

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm struggling for a few days now with using menu link as a selector.
It works with non-wordpress version of the same stuff, but when it comes to WP it drives me crazy. 
Here is youtube link with explanation and behaviour: https://youtu.be/SFx8TyPWhLg

I tried multiple codes, different selector paths:

```
nav.mobile>ul>li.menu-item-has-children>a
li.menu-item-has-children>a
.expand>a
.expand > a
```

and so on.

When I'm checking it's length it works correctly (with this code):

```
if ($('nav.mobile>ul>li.menu-item-has-children>a').length ) {
    // Do something
}
```

But it's doesn't do what needs to be done. 
Here are my jQuery codes (all works with li as a selector):

```
$('.expand>a  ').click(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').addClass('is_open');
    $('nav.mobile').addClass('is_submenu_open');

        setTimeout(function() {
            var offset = $('.is_open').offset();
             $('.close_menu').width(offset.left);
        }, 500)

    });

$(".expand>a ").on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().find("ul").addClass("is_open");
        $("nav.mobile").addClass('is_submenu_open');

        setTimeout(function() {
            var offset = $('.is_open').offset();
             $('.close_menu').width(offset.left);
        }, 500)
    });


 $(".expand>a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target !== this)
    return;
        $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").addClass(function() {
            $('.sub-menu').addClass("is_open");
            $('nav.mobile').addClass('is_submenu_open');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var offset = $('.is_open').offset();
                     $('.close_menu').width(offset.left);
                }, 500)
    });
 });
```

Here is HTML output for the menu:

```
<nav class="nav-header mobile" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-56"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2077" class="expand menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2077"><a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">What we do</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1883"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/what-we-do/search-acquisitions/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">SEARCH &#038; ACQUISITIONS</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1884"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/what-we-do/project-management/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">PROJECT MANAGEMENT</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1890" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1890"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/what-we-do/interior-architecture-design/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">INTERIOR ARCHITECTURE &#038; DESIGN</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1424"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/what-we-do/property-advisory/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">ADVISORY</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/what-we-do/investment/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Investment</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/what-we-do/home-management/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">HOME MANAGEMENT</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-333"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/case-histories/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Case Histories</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/rfr-scrapbook/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">RFR Scrapbook</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/news/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">News &#038; Press</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/team/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Team</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://www.rfr.dev/contact/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm just out of ideas what is wrong with it. 
Please, help.

Cheers, 
Kris

Comment: did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Hi, yes, all clear

Comment: you sure? because `$(nav.mobile>ul>li.menu-item-has-children>a)` this is **not** a valid javascript code

Comment: It's just sample, I know there must be quotes.
Exact code was:
if ($('nav.mobile>ul>li.menu-item-has-children>a').length ) {
...
}

Comment: so update the question

Comment: Try `closest()` instead of `parent()`. `$(this).closest("ul").addClass("is_open");`

Comment: Updated, sorry for error

Comment: @AndyTschiersch - doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, little mistake: Try this plz: `$(this).closest('ul').find("ul").addClass("is_open");`

Comment: @AndyTschiersch


Same behaviour as on my YT video, no change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
The problem was made by this part of css

```
.menu .menu-item > a:focus + ul.sub-menu,
.menu .menu-item.sfHover > ul.sub-menu {
    left: auto; //exactly this style
    opacity: 1;
}
```

In general, it's related to Genesis native Superfish.js that handles menu dropdowns.

simple change to my mobile.css nailed it

```
.menu .menu-item > a:focus + ul.sub-menu,
.menu .menu-item.sfHover > ul.sub-menu {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thank you @AndyTschiersch for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one and let me know whether the class `is_open` added to the submenu ul:

```
$(".expand > a > span").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("test");
    $(this).closest("li.expand").find("ul").addClass("is_open");
    $("nav.mobile").addClass('is_submenu_open');

    setTimeout(function() {
        var offset = $('.is_open').offset();
        $('.close_menu').width(offset.left);
    }, 500)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
But it doesn;t add that class

Comment: I have update my answer. Just added `console.log("test");`. Lets check whether this function is executed.

Comment: It's not executing the function with ".expand > a > span"  when I change it to just .expand and click outsite the "what we do" then it works. 
So same thing all the time, it looks like jQuery can't see that friggin a and span

Comment: Is it possible that css is making fun?
when I removed main stylesheet, it works...

Comment: Maybe this elements are not cleared? Can you check in inspector whether a and span has dimenson? In other words are they clickable?

Comment: It is.
Just found that something in Genesis Framework main style.css file is messing this up.
When I'm loading my child theme full css and mobile css, but remove GF styles, it works perfectly. 

I'll dig deeper and let you know. 

Many, many thanks!